# A function with the given name and argument types was not found. Why can't I search for trigram in m-t-m field?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, search, django-views

I have a provider model that has addresses that are linked with many-to-many relationship:
**addresses/models.py:**

```
class Street(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town, default=None, related_name='streets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='',
                        help_text='')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='')
...
```

The provider model itself **providers/models.py:**

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Street, db_index=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='providers', verbose_name='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='')
...
```

Next, I want to do a search for the client. The bottom line is that the client enters the name of the street, and as a result he gets a list of all providers that match the search query on the street. Since people tend to make mistakes in street names, I decided to use trigram. So this is the search query handler **home/views.py:**

```
def providers_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    query = None
    results = []
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = Provider.objects.annotate(
                similarity=TrigramSimilarity('location', query),
        ).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'query': query,
        'results': results,
}

return render(request, 'home/search.html', context)
```

And here is a simple form for entering a request **home/forms.py:**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
```

I end up getting an error that the function *similarity(integer, unknown)* does not exist (a function with the given name and argument types was not found. Perhaps you should add explicit casts).
Extension **pg_trgm** installed in postgresql. Pls, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a bug. Indeed, it is necessary to pass to the TrigramSimilarity method **'location__name'**:

```
...
if 'query' in request.GET:
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        query = form.cleaned_data['query']
        results = Provider.objects.annotate(
            similarity=TrigramSimilarity('location__name', query),
        ).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
...
```